# ARM32 write protection bit

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls, cpu-registers

On intel based architectures there's usually a CR0 register whose 16th (WP) bit forbids processes from writing in the kernel.

I'm looking for the equivalent in arm32 based systems, specifically armv7.

What I'm really trying to do is disable write protection (in C) such that i can then overwrite the syscall table, but I haven't really found any examples on how to do this other than the ones on the x86 platforms. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This seems very much like [an  XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... ***Why*** do you need to "overwrite the syscall table"? Especially, why do you want to do this from user-space?

Comment: I want to write wrappers for every syscall which would log the syscall and its parameters in a text file and then return the syscall.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: It is somewhat a "trend" for beginners in the Linux kernel to add their own behavior to the kernel by modifying existing syscalls. While intention to modify system calls doesn't look good in a long-term, for toy kernel modules this approach could be used.

Comment: @portarm: That sounds like what `strace` does, which it does largely by use of `ptrace`. You could also probably achieve similar by using the kernel's ftrace, or kprobes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't think you understand the *WP bit*.   The *WP* bit only affects code running at supervisor level (CPL < 3 in intel-ese).   It won't help your user mode program muck up the kernel.   Virtually no other cpu has such a thing as it makes almost no sense.   I suspect it was a late hack once they discovered they made copy-on-write nearly impossible to implement.